# asp.net page method with jquery and parameter

Tags: asp.net, json

In my javascript, I have:

```
var testdate = "{'TheNewDate' : '12/02/2011'}";

$("#mydiv").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Pages/Appointments.aspx/GetAppointements",
        data: testdate,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
            success: successFn,
        error: errorFn

    });
});
```

In my code behind I have

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetAppointements(string DateInput)
{
    var t = DateInput;
```

However, when I click to run the call, I get the error function to activate. When I change the code behind function to public static string GetAppointement() it works. But I guess my goal is to pass a parameter to the code behind. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameter is called `DateInput` and not `TheNewDate`, so:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Pages/Appointments.aspx/GetAppointements',
        data: JSON.stringify({ dateInput: '12/02/2011' }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it was just too easy! But it can take a while to figure out on your own.... thanks a lot.

Comment: @frenchie, also notice the usage of `JSON.stringify` instead of hardcoding strings which won't be properly encoded.

Comment: Quick question: the variables that I declared in my code behind page are not available in the page method; is this normal?

Comment: @frenchie, yes, that's perfectly normal. Static methods such as PageMethods should be have only access to static class members.

Comment: I have the userID that I need to access in the page method. For now it's just a number that's hard coded but later it'll be the real user's ID. How do I work around this in the page method? How do I authenticate the incoming request to belong this a particular user?

Comment: You could access the current HttpContext with the static `HttpContext.Current` property and so the currently logged in user with `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Comment: Ah!! And how do I set it in the first pass? Just HttpContext.Current.User = whatever ?

Comment: You don't set this property manually. It is automatically set by ASP.NET when a user logs in. For example if you are using [Forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) it could be done with the [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) method.

Comment: ok. In my application, TheUserID is a field that identifies each user. When the session begins, do I need to match the user's id as identified in my database with the user's Id defined by the asp.net engine?

Comment: @frenchie, I don't understand what ids you are talking about. In your question you didn't provide any description about your scenario and application. It's quite difficult to help under such circumstances. You also have access to the session in your PageMethod: `HttpContext.Current.Session`. I would also suggest you starting a new question about ASP.NET Page Methods if you have further doubts about how they work.

Comment: ok; I'll dig deeper and formalize another question. thanks for the json answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your JSON data match the parameter name in the web service method.

```
var testdate = "{'DateInput' : '12/02/2011'}";
```